# How do i set the width of an heatmap in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I created a simple heatmap with matplotlib with the following code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Display the image
ax.imshow(im)

a = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9],
              [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0],
              [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3],
              [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0],
              [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6]])

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.imshow(a, cmap='hot')
pos1 = ax1.get_position() # get the original position 
pos2 = [0.13, 0.15,  0.3, 0.3] 
ax1.set_position(pos2) # set a new position
```

This code works, the only problem is that i don't know how to make my heatmap wider. How can i set the width of an heatmap on MPL?

Comment: you are adding the `imshow` of the array `a` to a separate Axes instance to the image. Is there a reason for that? Do you want the imshow to fill the axes showing the image `im`? If so, you won't see the image any more. What is your expected outcome here?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm plotting the heatmap over an already existing image that i open from my code. The expected output is just to make the heatmap larger, while keeping its height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image can be positioned using the `extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1]` parameter of `imshow`. Without explicitly setting `extent`, the x goes from `-0.5` to `width-0.5`. This puts the ticks at integer positions nicely in the center of the cells.

As `imshow` resets the xlim to the last image drawn, these need to be set explicitly.

Optionally the aspect ratio can be set to 'auto' to make the image stretch with the dimensions of the surrounding figure.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot  as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Display the image
im = np.random.randn(5, 10).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)
ax.imshow(im)

a = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9],
              [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0],
              [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3],
              [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0],
              [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6]])
x0 = im.shape[1] - 0.5
x1 = x0 + a.shape[1]
ax.imshow(a, cmap='hot', extent=[x0, x1, -0.5, a.shape[0] - 0.5])
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, x1)
# ax.set_aspect('auto')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Note that `imshow` default starts drawing starting from the top. This can be changed by `imshow(..., origin='lower')`.